# Could a wasp be hurting my apple tree?

Tags: trees, fruit-trees, pests, apples

First of all, my apple tree is young, just about two feet tall. More importantly my apple tree is on my porch in a pot, and it's been there for at least, say, a month or two. Also, on my porch ceiling there are about 4 wasp nests of at least 3 different types (red ones, yellow and black ones, and small ones). They haven't ever stung, or even bothered, anyone, or any of my plants, including my other two much younger apple seedlings.

Recently, just this week, there has been one wasp (of either the red or the black and yellow kind) that has been sitting or moving back and forth on my oldest apple tree's leaves each day. it doesn't 'seem' to be doing anything bad to my apple tree, and it hasn't touched any of my other plants, but it won't go away and I'm not sure what to do about it.

Answer (score 7):

*Disclaimer: we haven't identified the wasps in question*

Wasps are insectivores. If they are flyng back and forth between or around plants, they are on the hunt or scouting for food.

The wasps' behaviour is harmless, but you might want to check your tree: if they suddenly hunt there a lot, it *may* indicate the presence of unwanted parasites like aphids.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing you need to worry about concerning wasps of any kind harming your baby trees. They are second level pollinators and rarely a problem for aggressiveness. You HAVE to send pictures of these insects.  Is there anything wrong with your little trees?  What are the winters like in India? What are your plans for these trees?  If they are relegated to the porch or balcony, that is fine!  They can be pruned or manipulated into espaliers for small spaces.  Great SOIL is important.  We've been working with another person from India that is unable to find good potting soil.  Is that true?  What have you been using?  Correct size pot for the size of the plant being transplanted.  Not the size it could reach but the size it is now.  Too big of a pot for a too small plant is very bad!  What kind of water and how often?  What kind of fertilizer and how often? You've got drainage holes in the pot?  How deep are these baby trees planted? (no soil on bark or the part of the trunk above the surface).  Wasps do not damage any plant.  Careful with guests that have allergies to bee/wasp stings.  Do you have a winter?  Sorry, I am clueless with India.  Hopefully our in house east Indian will pop in for comments. I am a hive type insect lover.

Answer (score 2):

Without picture we cannot identify the wasp, so I remain generic:

Wasps are very diverse types of insects. Usually they don't harm fruit trees. In facts, many wasps kill other insects and thus they help to control other pests. Some wasps eat also pollen, but one should rely on other pollinators.

But some types of wasp eat the apples (BTW usually these are wasps that build nests). If it is the case, you will see apples with only the core and most of skin, but with a large hole and most of pulp is missing (and probably you will see also some wasps).

So in general, I would check the fruit tree, and only I I would see problem, I would check is wasps are the cause.

But 4 wasp nest are too much, for me. If you risk, every time you check your fruits, to be picked by wasps, I'll considering to kill them, or to make the place less attractive, so they will choose a better place.